How to get the sudo permissions to the conatiner in openshift platform? on onpermises setup
I am facing below issue while running sudo command

sudo: The "no new privileges" flag is set, which prevents sudo from running as root.
sudo: If sudo is running in a container, you may need to adjust the container configuration to disable the flag

this is my yaml file i have used
- image: "{{ .Values.xyz.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.xyz.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.xyz.image.pullPolicy }}
        name: test
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
           privileged: true
          capabilities:
            drop: ["ALL"]
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 2000
          runAsGroup: 2000  # Replace with the appropriate group ID
          seccompProfile:
            type: RuntimeDefault

I want to run the sudo command inside the container
